# How do I setup python paths for selfmade modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ran into trouble while setting up a framework which I have been given. 
You can see the folder hierarchy of the framework in the pictures below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is with the imports of the **tug_resource_monitor_node.py** which you can see in the last image. 
Imports look like:

```
import rospy
from tug_resource_monitor.srv import *
import rosnode
import os
import psutil
from tug_resource_monitor.msg import NodeInfo, NodeInfoArray
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from tug_python_utils import YamlHelper as Config
```

I get the following error message: No module named tug_resource_monitor.srv

I have already tried adding the python module through: `sys.path.insert(0, "/home/username/catkin_ws/model_based_diagnosis/")` (at the beginning of the **tug_resource_monitor_node.py** file)
I also tried adding the path to **.profile** by adding the following line:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/username/catkin_ws/model_based_diagnosis
```

Unfortunately none of the above worked. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing import to `from model_based_diagnosis.tug_resource_monitor.srv import *` will work.

```
catkin_ws/
└── model_based_diagnosis
    ├── __init__.py
    └── tug_resource_monitor
        ├── scripts
        │   └── tug_resource_monitor_node.py
        └── srv
            ├── __init__.py
            └── test_import.py

~$ pwd
/Users/username/catkin_ws/model_based_diagnosis/tug_resource_monitor/scripts

~$ python tug_resource_monitor_node.py 
import module from srv
Import form  /Users/username/catkin_ws/model_based_diagnosis/tug_resource_monitor/srv/test_import.py
```

and code I used to test

```
~$ cat tug_resource_monitor_node.py 
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/username/catkin_ws")
from model_based_diagnosis.tug_resource_monitor.srv import test_import
print("import module from srv")
test_import.import_test()
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I guess there is something wrong with my pythonpath. 

echo $PYTHONPATH gives me the following result:

/home/username/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/username/catkin_ws/model_based_diagnosis:/home/username/catkin_ws/model_based_diagnosis

Comment: Can you try changing your export statement to 
`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/username/catkin_ws/` ?

Comment: I found the problem. I set up my folder structure incorrectly. Thank you guys for your support.

Answer (score 1):

1
try 
`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/username/catkin_ws/model_based_diagnosis/scripts`

2 try `from tug_resource_monitor import *`